# Deleting post via ajax in Laravel 5.5. Works after refresh page

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm new in Laravel.

When I click delete nothing happen, after refresh page the post deleting.

My controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request)

{

    if(isset($request->id)){
          $post = Post::findOrFail($request->id);
          $post->delete();
    }

 }
```

my route

```
Route::delete('/adminpanel/dashboard/posts/', 'Adminpanel\PostsController@destroy')->name('post.delete');
```

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" data-post="{{ $post->id }}">
i class="fas fa-minus"></i></a>
```

javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.deletebtn', function(ev){
        let postid = $(this).attr("data-post");
        $.ajax({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: '{{ route('post.delete') }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id:postid,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},

            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },

            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to reload your page after Ajax success.

Comment: please explain it

Comment: i need whole page reload?

Comment: No, you could reload the element contains your items.

Comment: It would be helpful to attach a screenshot of your interface.

Comment: do you have `Route::resource` for this ?

Comment: no, i did it manually to figure it out

Comment: this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

**Option #1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.deletebtn', function(ev){
        let postid = $(this).attr("data-post");
        $.ajax({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: '{{ route('post.delete') }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id:postid,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},

            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            },

            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Option #2:** in your controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request)

{

    if(isset($request->id)){
          $post = Post::findOrFail($request->id);
          $post->delete();
          return redirect()->back();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you @lewis4u

Comment: @Zuma Maybe you are missing csrf_token headers? for ajax

Comment: can you explain it more

Comment: @Zuma, what is the current state, what error do you get?

Comment: there is no error, everything okay.  when i click delete its just stay and nothing happen, and when i  reload the page it delete it

Comment: id: 123
_token: AeTQZgAFvfEWYaDttoKhTjc9gp1sbD6U6lQgwOVD

Comment: @Zuma put `window.location.reload();` in success method and try it

Comment: What browser are you using and what is the version?

Comment: chrome last for mac

Comment: Test it with Firefox and let me know

Comment: i tested it on firefox and safari, result is the same

Comment: i can't understand what is the reason, maybe it has some other way to implement it?

Comment: Yes, no using Ajax

Comment: Welcome dear @Zuma

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari hame post ha va comment haye shoma ra `upvote` kardam movafagh bashid